# How to integrate a python script with amavis or spamassasin?

Tags: postfix, perl, spamassassin, amavis

I have an MTA setup with postfix acting as MTA and Amavis acting as content filter; Amavis is configured for using SpamAssassin and Clamav. I have written a Python script that basically analyses an email and gives a score. I want to integrate in the current setup such that this script can be used and score output can be fed in the form of a new header in the original email. I tried doing it using the policy in Amavis but I failed. Can anyone guide me what are my options and how it can be done?

Comment: https://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html, https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html